# iPhone simulator shows blank white screen after application launch

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone application development, and I am building a new calculator just to see how everything works.
I completed my code, but when I run the application, it does not show anything on the simulator.
I have created a number pad, but the screen is blank (white) after the application launches.
Can anyone give me a pointer, please?
I am using Xcode 4.2 and deployment target is 5.0

Comment: I suggest showing us the code you use in applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using empty template for your project them make sure that you are correctly adding your view to window in appdelegate file in function named applicationDidFinishLaunching.

It can also happen when you target for iphone and using xid file related to ipad or another way.

hope it will help you and sorry for my bad english